# UTF8 problems while working with DOM Object in PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have some UTF8 text+image data which must be processed.

My whole code is in one file; here is the complete code:

```
<?php
echo "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /></head><body>";

$article_header="აბგდევზთ<img src='some_url/img/15.jpg' alt=''>აბგდევზთ";
echo "1".$article_header."<br>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
 if(!$img->getAttribute('class')){
$src = $img->getAttribute('src');
$newSRC = str_replace('/img/', '/mini/', $src);
$img->setAttribute('src', $newSRC);
$img->removeAttribute('width'); 
$img->removeAttribute('height');
$article_header = $doc->saveHTML();
            }
                        }
echo "2".$article_header."<br>";
echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

As you see I echo data 2 times.

- The first time, it brings both text and image, as expected.
- The second time, it brings the modified image as expected. But the text becomes damaged, like this: `áƒáƒ‘áƒ’áƒ“áƒ”áƒ•áƒ–áƒ—`

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: The text encoding of the page seems to be set correctly, so it might have something to do with the PHP file itself. Did you save it encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: file has utf8 encoding. So everything looks good for me too. But the problem still exists

Comment: My editor can't recognize these characters either. Are you sure these are UTF-8?

Comment: Those are georgian letters. u can try russian letters if u want. result is the same. Or even better write here your utf8 letters which u think are OK, and I'll give them a try.

Comment: I tried traditional chinese (檢測 - test) which both work. I have also tested greek (δοκιμή - test), works aswell.

Comment: Gave them a try. Both chineese and greek letters are ok in the beginning nad destroyed in the end in my example. Can u compare your code with mine ? maybe u have some differences ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys I've found the solution!!!!!!!!!! Huraaa !!!! :))))
For those who will face this problem in future here is the code

```
$article_header = mb_convert_encoding($article_header, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

This must be done before loadHTML and everything works fine!!!!